# C++: will an std::runtime_error object leak in a longjmp?

Tags: c++, exception, setjmp

Suppose I have some C++ code which has a try-catch block in which the `catch` part will trigger a long jump:

```c
#include <stdexcept>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <setjmp.h>

void my_fun()
{
    jmp_buf jump_buffer;
    if (setjmp(jump_buffer))
        return;
    
    try {
        std::string message;
        message.resize(100);
        snprintf(&message[0], 100, "error code %d\n", 3);
        throw std::runtime_error(message);
    }

    catch (std::runtime_error &e) {
        longjmp(jump_buffer, 1);
    }
}
```

Since the `std::runtime_error` object was allocated dynamically somewhere, will it leak the memory that was allocated for it or for the string?

Comment: That won't leak on a conforming implementation.  Lifetime management of exception objects and proper unwinding when exception handling is combined with `longjmp` are definitely some of the more complicated/challenging things a C++ implementation has to deal with, so there's a likelihood of non-conformance in the real world.

Comment: To expand on what @BenVoigt said ["It depends"](https://godbolt.org/z/6hcx8fEn8), the runtime won't leak insofar as you return to the jump point it seems.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is kind of complicated. About `longjmp`'s validity, [the standard says:](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/csetjmp.syn#2)

> A setjmp/longjmp call pair has undefined behavior if replacing the setjmp and longjmp by catch and throw would invoke any non-trivial destructors for any objects with automatic storage duration.

`runtime_error` has a non-trivial destructor, so the question is whether the exception object has "automatic storage duration". It does not. This suggests that `longjmp` should be fine.

In addition, [exception object destruction can happen in one of two places](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/except.throw#4):

> The points of potential destruction for the exception object are:
>
> - when an active handler for the exception exits by any means other than rethrowing, immediately after the destruction of the object (if any) declared in the exception-declaration in the handler;
> - when an object of type std​::​exception_­ptr that refers to the exception object is destroyed, before the destructor of std​::​exception_­ptr returns.

`longjmp` is not "rethrowing". So in theory, this should be fine thanks to bullet point 1.

That being said, ***never rely on this***. I highly doubt that implementations of `longjmp` handle this correctly, and even if some do, it's probably not something you can expect.

Comment: It indeed ends up leaking with GCC if the jump is a global variable set in a different function.

Answer (score 4):

There is actually a C++ defect report about this specific case, http://wg21.link/cwg2361 . So right now it is up in the air what is correct.

Comment: While I think it is a positive you dug that up, I believe this is a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: No, it's an answer. The question is "will it leak?" and the answer is "the standard is unclear".

Answer (score 2):

Why you would even want to do something like this is beyond me.
But the question was intruiging. I know you can't jump into a catch block,
and that jumping out of it (also goto :( ) is allowed.

It seems the exception is destructed just after leaving the catch scope. And nothing leaks. Here is the output of the test program below :

```
scope: normal_try_catch::try entered
exception constructed
scope : normal_try_catch::try left
scope : normal_try_catch::catch entered
scope : normal_try_catch::catch left
exception destructed
----------------------------
scope : long_jump_catch::try entered
exception constructed
scope : long_jump_catch::try left
scope : long_jump_catch::catch entered
scope : long_jump_catch::catch left
exception destructed
scope : long_jump_catch::leave because of setjmp entered
scope : long_jump_catch::leave because of setjmp left
```

So the exception is cleaned up before the jump is made.

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <setjmp.h>

class my_except :
    public std::exception
{
public:
    my_except() 
    {
        std::cout << "exception constructed" << std::endl;
    }

    ~my_except()
    {
        std::cout << "exception destructed" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct scope
{
    explicit scope(const std::string& scope) :
        m_scope{ scope }
    {
        std::cout << "scope : " << m_scope << " entered" << std::endl;
    }

    ~scope()
    {
        std::cout << "scope : " << m_scope << " left" << std::endl;
    }


private:
    std::string m_scope;
};


void normal_try_catch()
{
    try
    {
        scope s{ "normal_try_catch::try" };
        throw my_except();
    }
    catch(const std::exception&)
    {
        scope s{ "normal_try_catch::catch" };
    }
}

void long_jump_catch()
{
    jmp_buf jump_buffer;
    if (setjmp(jump_buffer))
    {
        scope s{ "long_jump_catch::leave because of setjmp" };
        return;
    }

    try
    {
        scope s{ "long_jump_catch::try" };
        throw my_except();
    }
    catch (const std::exception&)
    {
        scope s{ "long_jump_catch::catch" };
        longjmp(jump_buffer, 1);
    }
}


int main()
{
    normal_try_catch();
    std::cout << "----------------------------" << std::endl;
    long_jump_catch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful. It seems however that if the jump is set instead to a point before the function call, the exception will actually end up leaking under GCC. And the reason I wanted to do this in the first place was to pass a callback to C code which does error handling through long jumps.

Comment: After reading the standard, this behavior may be specific to MSVC (19).  Since I am not invoking "trivial destructors", so if I understood correctly this is undefined behavior.